# Как организовать общение в формате JSON сервера и клиента по сокетам на Java просто и правильно?

Tags: java, android, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер

**Задача:**

Сервер и клиенты должны обмениваться информацией в реальном времени. Например в виде JSON сообщений.

**Проблема:**

*На сервере:* Не очень понятно какие есть готовые решения для этой задачи и так ли она решается. В данный момент есть `Echo` сервер на `Netty`. Это как-то совсем низкоуровнево. Кажется абсурдным, что надо массивы байтов либо по символу переноса строки отделять друг от друга, либо придумывать какой-то свой разделитель и его отлавливать в байтах.

*На клиенте:* В качестве клиента, например, берём андроид приложение. Я пробовал https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java но так и не удалось заставить это работать. Попробовал `OkHttp`, но он сначала шлёт на сервер параметры запроса по адресу (заголовки какие-то etc), а потом выдаёт ошибку при приёме этих его заголовков в ответе сервера: `java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line {ТУТ ЗАГОЛОВОК ЗАПРОСА К СЕРВЕРУ}`

**Вопрос:**

Как всё это делается по феншую? Что в гугл вбивать?

<s>Должны же быть какие-то стандарты и библиотеки... Вот только как же их искать(</s>

**UPD_0:**

После добавления `HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake` в начале сообщения от сервера падать перестало. Теперь просто молчит. Ни сервер, ни клиент не получают сообщения. Похоже что клиентская реализация ожидает какой-то последовательности строк от сервера на свои запросы описанной в каком-то стандарте. Отсюда вопрос - неужто надо вычитывать какие-то стандарты или для сервера есть готовые решения, которые позволят сосредоточиться на собственно общении, а не на строгом следовании каким-то там протоколам?

Comment: Юзал webSocket. Не знаю как там на сервере, но работает нормально.

Comment: Использую Socket.IO.

Comment: Вот хорошая статья: https://stfalcon.com/ru/blog/post/android-websocket

Comment: Спасибо, статью и либу нашёл. Она, вроде, мне подходит, но проблема такая же как и в случае с OkHttp - сокету на стороне клиента хочется какой-то строго определённой реакции от сервера. В данный момент он у меня принятую строку оборачивает в JSON и постит обратно клиенту. Клиент падает с сообщением `com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketException: The status line of the opening handshake response is badly formatted. The status line is: MyMessage{mMessage='GET / HTTP/1.1'}`

Comment: Спасибо, в итоге помогли комменты нагуглить подходящие либы для сервера и клиента)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в нужде реализации протокола обмена данными между сервером и клиентом. Т.е. сервер должен подтверждать успешность соединения, читать заголовки, отвечать специальными сообщениями и делать прочие реверансы, описанные в стандартах. Использованная сначала на сервере [Netty](https://netty.io/) совсем низкоуровневая, протокол там надо самостоятельно реализовывать. Используемые же клиентские либы требовали уже реализованный протокол на сервере. Видимо можно использовать также изначальную реализацию сокетов на клиенте и руками разбирать байты. Но это, конечно, не решение.

В итоге нашёл вот такое решение для сервера: либа [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket).

Для клиента использовал либу [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)

В итоге получается не ковырять байты, но переругиваться `JSON`-ами, что и требовалось.

Comment: в https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket есть пример реализации клиента для андроида, и эта библиотека хорошо работает и по wss.и клиентом сервера может быть и браузер и андроид.

Comment: @Вадим, спасибо, но я не смог с ходу там найти пример для андроида)

Answer (score 0):

@ЮрийСПб вот сам клиент https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java
вот тут использование https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/tree/master/src/main/example
для андроида желательно клиента оформить в в виде сервиса