# Сокет клиент и Сокет Сервер. Андроид

Tags: java, android, сокет, websocket, клиент-сервер

Только начал изучать сокеты и мучает один вопрос. Во всех примерах сервер пишут на том же ява. Можно ли написать клиент на ява а сервер на php. Что то подсказывает что можно но все же пока не услышу не усну.

Comment: да можно (7 символов нужно...)

Comment: @Виктор для чего нужно 7 символов?

Comment: 7 символов для комментария. Ответ на ваш вопрос - да можно, но это вам вопрос к PHP разработчикам.

Comment: Ваш клиент ( приложение) общается с сервером по протоколу. ему всё равно, что там за язык на сервере

Comment: @user8978194 пишут и на php, только это выглядит как костыль. сервер на java - это полноценное приложение, а сервер на php - это обработчик обращений. а всякие демоны на php - это попытки сделать нечто похожее на приложение...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общение по сокетам представляет собой обмен информацией в виде байтов. Реализовать это можно на любом языке.

При этом общение должно происходить по правилам. Набор правил называют протоколом. Он определяет, например, как нужно байты разделять на отдельные сообщения. Обычно не изобретают свой протокол, а используют имеющиеся реализации. Например протокол `WebSocket` для которого есть [либы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/732836/17609) почти на любом языке.

Ещё один вариант протокола - `HTTP` - он также [просто открывает соединение](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-01-05-websockets-vs-rest-api-understanding-the-difference/) по сокетам, сервер и клиент обмениваются определёнными протоколом сообщениями, после чего соединение закрывается. Например один из этапов запроса по схеме `https` является обмен сертификатами (`handshake`) ошибку которого иногда можно увидеть в логах при попытке сделать `https` запрос.

Comment: в качестве дополнения скажу, что появился HTTP/2 это замена веб сокетам. т.е. http коннекшны которые закрываются не сразу, а держаться пока не выполнится условие закрытия.

Comment: @SviatVolkov, не буду возражать, если вы это в ответ добавите)

Comment: @Sviat Volkov  HTTP/2 это не замена websocket, это огромный шаг назад. и это огромный тормоз в продвижении  HTTP/2 .