# C помощью чего реализовать передачу информации с сервера к клиенту

Tags: java

Сабж. 
Сервер должен отправлять 50-ти клиентам каждую секунду информацию (для всех клиентов одинаковая) в формате JSON, после того как они "подпишутся" на сервер отправив определенные данные. Подойдет ли для этих целей java.net.ServerSocket? Сильная ли нагрузка будет на него? Размер отправляемых данных к клиенту - 5-10кб. Только открываю для себя мир серверов, поэтому решил спросить у Вас. Спасибо!

Comment: Android или standalone?

Comment: standalone 123456

Comment: Не сильная нагрузка. Потянет. `java.net.ServerSocket` - плохо, готовые библиотеки вроде netty - хорошо. `5-10кб` одним запросом - плохо, лучше разбить на подзапросы.

Comment: @Suvitruf, netty же сильно низкоуровневая... Думаю, если webSocket использовать, то всё быстрее и проще выйдет сделать. Вот тут можно посмотреть как я такую проблему решал для андроида: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/732836/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб зато полный контроль за пайплайном )

Comment: @Suvitruf, как мне кажется, если задача просто JSON гонять, то контроль не нужен)

Comment: Всем спасибо! Этого достаточно!